# Django password in node.js

Tags: django, node.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to do some authentication from my previous django web app in node. I got `PBKDF2-sha256` working but I'm not able to get the `BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher` working in Node. I tried the following:

```
var Bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var sha256 = require('sha256');

var pass = sha256("test password")

// from django ("bcrypt_sha256$$2b$12$mUg9hoKn0tt2/VwWaNb6Euie4.jtQjfU6.CY1pT0EH8GPORqAsh66")
var hash = "$2b$12$mUg9hoKn0tt2/VwWaNb6Euie4.jtQjfU6.CY1pT0EH8GPORqAsh66" 
Bcrypt.compare(pass, hash, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('do they match?', isMatch);
});
```

Is there something i'm missing with the above? I'm taking the `sha256` of the password and testing with `bcrypt`. The corresponding code in Django is below:

```python
def verify(self, password, encoded):
    algorithm, data = encoded.split('$', 1)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm
    bcrypt = self._load_library()

    # Hash the password prior to using bcrypt to prevent password truncation
    #   See: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20138
    if self.digest is not None:
        # We use binascii.hexlify here because Python3 decided that a hex encoded
        #   bytestring is somehow a unicode.
        password = binascii.hexlify(self.digest(force_bytes(password)).digest())
    else:
        password = force_bytes(password)

    # Ensure that our data is a bytestring
    data = force_bytes(data)
    # force_bytes() necessary for py-bcrypt compatibility
    hashpw = force_bytes(bcrypt.hashpw(password, data))

    return constant_time_compare(data, hashpw)
```

**UPDATE**

I have no idea why, but when I change the salt slightly to the following:

```
var hash = "$2a$12$mUg9hoKn0tt2/VwWaNb6Euie4.jtQjfU6.CY1pT0EH8GPORqAsh66"
```

everything works! I changed the `2b` to `2a` at the beginning. Why is this working and the other isn't? Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [excellent Passlib library](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html?highlight=bcrypt#passlib.hash.bcrypt):

> 1. ident (str) – Specifies which version of the BCrypt algorithm will be used when creating a new hash. Typically this option is not needed,
>      as the default ("2a") is usually the correct choice. If specified, it
>      must be one of the following:
>
>    - "2" - the first revision of BCrypt, which suffers from a minor security flaw and is generally not used anymore. "2a" - some
>        implementations suffered from a very rare security flaw. current
>        default for compatibility purposes.
>    - "2y" - format specific to the crypt_blowfish BCrypt implementation, identical to "2a" in all but name.
>    - **"2b" - latest revision of the official BCrypt algorithm (will be default in Passlib 1.7)**.

Comment: But is there a solution for this in node as yet? I tried `node-bcrypt` and also `bcrypt`. Neither of them support `2b`.

Comment: seems it is not implemented yet, checked this and there is no `2b` https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt/blob/master/bCrypt.js#L559

Comment: Yeah, I saw that also.

Comment: so I guess the solution is to replace all the `2b` by a `2a` before using your hashs

Comment: NOTE: If anyone is also trying to share Bcrypt passwords between Python and Node.js apps, try using `bcryptjs` npm package instead of the C++ based `bcrypt` package. Tjhat one I have verified to work with passwords prefixed with 2y